# Prime races in two competing arithmetic progressions - error bound

Tags: analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta-function, dirichlet-series

I read an article by Andrew Granville on the subject, there's actually quite a bit of recent literature on the topic. My problem is as follows. I have two sequences of primes: $(p_{1,n})$ and $(p_{3,n})$, respectively primes of the form $4k+1$ and $4k+3$. Because all odd squares are also of the form $4k+1$, there is a bias (Chebyshev's bias): the race is not fair.

Anyway, I am wondering if there are some known bounds on the error term $p_{1,n}-p_{3,n}$. If I read and interpreted correctly, it is reasonable to expect that $|p_{1,n}-p_{3,n}|/  \sqrt{n\log\log n}$ is bounded? I could not find a reference about it. Is it a proven fact? This is the law of the iterated logarithm, I would assume it could be plausible if the race is fair, but this is not the case here (well it is fair but only *asymptotically*). Do you know the exact statement (or the correct version if mine is wrong) and whether it is unconditional to GRH? I am definitely looking for an unconditional result even if much weaker, especially unconditional to the conjecture that $L(s,\chi_4)$ has no root if
$\Re(s)>\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: The usually studied quantities are $\pi(x;q,a):=\#\{p \le x: p \equiv a \bmod q\}$ so that $p_{i,n}$ ($i\in \{1,3\}$) is the smallest number with $\pi(p_{i,n};4,i)=n$. Under GRH, $(*)\, \pi(x;4,1)-\pi(x;4,3)= O(\sqrt{x}\log x)$ (see Corollary 13.8 in Montgomery and Vaughan's book). It is known that this difference is $\Omega(\sqrt{x}(\log x)^{-1}\log \log \log x)$ (p. 481 of said book) and it is conjectured that the difference is $O(\sqrt{x}(\log x)^{-1}(\log \log \log x)^2)$ and that this is best possible (see p. 484 of said book). All of this follows from the explicit formula.

Comment: PNT in arithmetic progressions shows $p_{i,n} \sim 2n\log n$ and with a bit of work, $(*)$ (or rather GRH in the form $\pi(x;4,i) = \mathrm{Li}(x)/2 + O(\sqrt{x} \log x)$) implies that $p_{1,n}-p_{3,n} = O(\sqrt{n}(\log n)^{5/2})$, if I didn't mess the power of log. Using conjectural bounds for $\pi(x;4,i)-\mathrm{Li}(x)/2$ one can do a bit better. The conjecture from the previous comment is related to probabilistic models for $(\sum_{\rho} x^{\rho}/\rho)/\sqrt{x}$, whose maximum one wants to understand. See the literature referred to in p. 484 (Monach and Montgomery).

Comment: Thank you Ofir. If I you use $O((n \log n)^{r+\epsilon})$ for the bound, it seems you can prove this weak version of GRH, if my reasoning is correct: no root for $L(s,\chi_4)$ if $\Re(s)>r$. I want to avoid GRH. I assume getting the strength $r=\frac{1}{2}$ without GRH is hopeless, so looking for something weaker.  Maybe $r=3/4$, not using GRH.